# Oracle select query from table with custom datatypes

Tags: oracle, custom-data-type

I have inherited a project with an old Oracle database with tables that contain custom datatype columns:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB_DOWNLOAD (
    JOBID      NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    MSGHEADER  MSGHEADERTYPE,  --Custom DataType
    PAYLOAD    PAYLOADLISTTYPE --Custom DataType
);
```

I can run a `SELECT` on the table and select just the `JOBID` column and get results, however as soon as I try to select any of the custom DataType columns I receive the error `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier`

I have searched around and everything suggests it is due to an invalid column name. I have tried the following queries, all return the same error message:

```
SELECT * FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD
SELECT JOBID, MSGHEADER, PAYLOAD, FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD
SELECT MSGHEADER  FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD
SELECT PAYLOAD FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD
SELECT MSGHEADER AS "MessageHead" FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD
```

Is there anything else I can do to help diagnose the cause of the error?

Thanks.

Edit:
An example of one of the custom types:

```
CREATE type msgheadertype as object
( destination       destinationtype
, org           varchar2(20)
)
```

Edit2:
I looked at the `PAYLOADLISTTYPE` and it is slightly different:

```
CREATE type payloadlisttype as table of transactiontype
```

Then `transactiontype`:

```
CREATE TYPE transactiontype as object
( header            headertype
, data          datatype
)
```

`headertype` and `datatype` then also nest custom data types, which nest custom types, there are custom datatypes down 7 layers if that makes a difference

Edit3:
Querying `ALL_OBJECTS` for the top level data types returns:

```
OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS
----------------------------------
MSGHEADERTYPE,   TYPE,    VALID
MSGHEADERTYPE,   SYNONYM, VALID
PAYLOADLISTTYPE, TYPE,    VALID
```

I only ran this against the top level data types, does it need to be done at all levels?

Comment: I would recommend you to check whether those datatypes are valid within the database first. Then, provide those datatype structures here so we can be of any assist.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have added one of the datatypes. I am not an Oracle expert, could provide an example of how to check if a datatype is valid?

Comment: Also, take a look at the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch_objs.htm

Comment: Something in the lines of: `select object_name, object_type, status from user_objects where OBJECT_NAME = 'MSGHEADERTYPE'`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I ran the script and it returns no records, I also ran it without the `where` to try and see if there were any, but it also returned no results.

Comment: Then your user does not have enough privileges. Try the same select statement with the `all_objects` view instead of `user_objects`

Comment: Thanks, `all_objects` worked. I have updated the question with the results.

Comment: You say an old database - how old? What is the Oracle version?

Comment: @MT0, from the documentation I have, looks like it was built in the '90s (Oracle 7). Currently it is version 10.2.0.4.0

Comment: If you run `SELECT name, value, description FROM v$parameter WHERE name='compatible';` is the database compatible with 10.2 or is it set to an earlier version?

Comment: @MT0 I tried to run the `v$parameter` query but I get an error: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` I got the version number by running `SELECT * FROM v$version`

Comment: If the top level are all valid then the down level should also be valid. Just in case, you can use the select i gave with the where clause `OBJECT_NAME in ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2', 'TYPE3',.....,'LASTTYPE')`. So in order to select those data in a sql query you need to go down until reach the last object like: `select JOBID, MSGHEADER.NEXTTYPE.NEXTTYPE......LASTTYPE`. Another problem that i can think of is you are having problem with some SYNONYM for one (or more)  of those types down the road. Which can be caused by user permissions... I think you may need from the people who manage the database...

Comment: If there isn't anyone, you have a really messy problem to track down...

Answer (score 1):

Use a table alias:

```
SELECT JOBID,
       j.MSGHEADER,
       j.PAYLOAD
FROM   JOB_DOWNLOAD j
```

or, to get the attributes within the types:

```
SELECT JOBID,
       j.MSGHEADER.destination,
       j.MSGHEADER.org,
       j.PAYLOAD.column1,
       j.PAYLOAD.column2
FROM   JOB_DOWNLOAD j
```

Comment: The table alias did not solve the problem, but trying to get the attribute returns a more specific error: `ORA-00904: "J"."MSGHEADER"."DESTINATION": invalid identifier` It returns the same error for all of the attributes, with the attribute matching the one selected.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to convert the PL/SQL type column to XML:

```
SELECT XMLTYPE( MSGHEADER ),
XMLTYPE(PAYLOAD)
FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD;
```

If you want to display only specific values, use extractvalue:

```
SELECT extractvalue( XMLTYPE( MSGHEADER ), 'PAYLOADLISTTYPE/DESTINATION')
FROM JOB_DOWNLOAD;
```

You might want to inspect te resulting XML to find out what the actual path is you want to provide as a parameter in the extractvalue function.